# How to create recyclerview where the view input is dynamic

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a system where I get a custom view from a library. I do not have access to the view itself but I have an api call to return the view. I want to use this view in a recyclerview. Since I do not have access to the class, I cannot create a < customview > type object in my listItem xml class. Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and whenever you're required to return the view use such API call to instantiate the new view from your `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```kotlin
class Adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = dataSet[position].viewType

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
       return when(viewType) {
            // I suggest to assign this to a constant variable CUSTOM_VIEW for more readability
            1 -> CustomViewHolder.create(…)
            else -> OtherStuff from your collection
            
       }
    }
}
```

And as long as all views `extend` the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` you should be good to go.

Comment: This view extends the exoplayer PlayerView so I guess that should work? Let me try it out tho.

Comment: Yes you have to wrap it into your own ViewHolder. You can just create a layout file with just a `FrameLayout`and programatically add the ExoPlayer view inside of it